# How do I draw text at the center of a rectangle in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

So I just wanna get some words written in the centre of the rectangles like 'Play Game' or something like that and I'm not exactly sure what to really do.

```
def drawText(text, x, y, fSize):
    screen_text = pygame.font.SysFont("Calibri", fSize, True).render(text, True, (0, 0, 0))
    rect = screen_text.get_rect()
    rect.center = ((screen_side_length // 2) + x), ((screen_side_length // 2) + y)
    screen.blit(screen_text, rect)

def main_menu():
    user_choice = None
    while user_choice == None:
        screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
        drawText('main menu', 0, 0, 20)

        x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        button_1 = pygame.Rect(50, 100, 200, 50)
        button_2 = pygame.Rect(50, 200, 200, 50)

        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), button_1)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), button_2)
        
        click = False
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 1:
                    click = True
                
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)
    return user_choice
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the center of the text rectangle:

```py
font = pygame.font.SysFont("Calibri", fSize, True) 

def drawTextCenter(text, centerx, centery, fSize):
    font.render(text, True, (0, 0, 0)) 
    rect = screen_text.get_rect(center = (centerx, centery))
    screen.blit(screen_text, rect)
```

Pass the center of the rectangle to the `drawTextCenter` function:

```py
button_1 = pygame.Rect(50, 100, 200, 50)
drawTextCenter('main menu', button_1.centerx, button_1.centery, 20)
```

Do not create the `pygame.font.Font` object in every frame. Create the font once at the begin of the program. Creating a font object is very time consuming because the font file has to be read and interpreted.